# Tomcat In-Memory Caching - replication on Cluster

Tags: java, tomcat, caching

I have a question on Tomcat clustering. I have a java application in which we have implemented in-memory caching. So basically when Tomcat starts, it loads a few objects from the database. These objects are stored in the tomcat memory like static objects. so whenever we update something from the application, it writes to the database and also updates the object in memory.

My question is, if we implement clustering in tomcat with 2 or more nodes, will those cached objects be also shared? Is that possible? I dont think it is. HttpSession objects can be shared using the session replication provided by tomcat delta manager or backup manager. But can the in-memory things also be shared?

Additionally what happens to batch jobs that are running? Will they also run multiple times as there will be multiple tomcat instances in the cluster and they would each trigger the job? That would be a failure as well as.

Any thoughts \ ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you save something in memory, it will not be replicated unless you implement something specifically to send it to other machines. Each jvm keeps their memory independent from each other.

In general, if you want to have replicated caching, a good solution is to use ehcache (http://www.ehcache.org/).

With regard to batch jobs, it depends on the library you use but generally, if you use an established library (like http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), it should be capable of making sure that only one instance runs the job. Perhaps you need to configure.

The important thing is to test to make sure that any solution you put in place actually does what you expect it to do.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever moving to a cluster or a cluster-like topology you need to revise your application solution design/architecture to make sure it will support multiple instance execution.

1. Data cached in memory by a given Tomcat instance WILL NOT be shared across instances in the cluster. You will need to move such data outside the Tomcat instance to a shared cache instance - Redis seems to be a popular option this days.
2. Job execution probably needs to be revised and customized to be driven by configuration. Create a Boolean flag your app can read and kick off batch processing if required. Select the node within the cluster you need the job to run on and set the flag to true there. Set it to false in all other nodes. Quartz WILL NOT ensure/control/manage multiple instances of a job running in a cluster.